# Where отобрать по списку значений

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть две модели 
Категории:

```
public class Categories
{
    public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
    public int? StoroniyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Parent_id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Products> Produkt { get; set; }
}
```

Parent_id идентификатор родительской категории

Модель Товары

```
public class Products
    {
        public int ProductsId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
        public virtual Categories Categoria { get; set; }
        public int Possition { get; set; }
        public bool Glass { get; set; }
        public decimal price_opt { get; set; }
        public decimal price_rrc { get; set; }        
    }
```

Никак не получается отобрать товары по родительской категории:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var CatId = await _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent_id == 3).ToListAsync();
    var applicationDbContext = _context.Products.Where(c => CatId.Equals(c.CategoriesId));
    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Как в этом случае правильно прописать оператор Where

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дали на англоязычной версии:

Вы должны изменить соответствующую строку в строке ниже

```
var applicationDbContext = _context.Products.Where(c => CatId.Any(cat => cat.CategoriesId == c.CategoriesId));
```

Вы получаете список категорий в первом where пункте , так что вы должны проверить , если принадлежит продукту ко всем таким категориям.

Я хотел бы сделать это немного по-другому, хотя

```
var products = from c in _context.Categories
               from p in _context.Products
               where c.CategoriesId == p.CategoriesId && c.Parent_id == 3
               select p;

return View(await products.ToListAsync());
```

Ссылка на оригинал [Ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014694/where-select-by-list-of-values/43015089#43015089)